# Angular - Images and icons disappear from the page after change detection is triggered

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-changedetection

I have an Angular (v12) webpage with several images and icons. These images are either svg, png or icons imported by the ngb library. When the page loads initially, all the icons and images render properly with no issues.

I also have OIDC configured in my project. So whenever the `silentRenewal` method of OIDC is called, it internally triggers change detection. After the change detection, many of the images and icons disappear from the page.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dOQe.png) | [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjLPw.png)

When I inspect the icons, their URLs are correct and they open perfectly in a new tab, it is just they don't render on the page.

It is not just a single component that is being affected by this. Icons of many components like header, side-bar dashboard etc. disappear after the OIDC method is called.

I am only able to reproduce this issue in Chrome, Safari, and Edge browsers. Firefox renders the icons properly.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "npm --no-git-tag-version version patch",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "^11.0.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^13.0.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.4",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.0.1",
    "angular-multi-step-form": "^1.2.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.8",
    "ng-template": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.181",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Things that I have tried to resolve it:

- Triggering change detection manually by applying `changeDetectionStretegy` `onPush` at component level and using `changeDetectorRef` at `afterViewInit` cycle.
- Changing URLs of images and icons to use absolute path instead of relative path.

None of these resolved the issue.

Comment: No error in the console? We need to see more of your code, please (controller, html, css)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Flo there is no error as well as warning in the console.

Comment: maybe provide your OIDC code? I am not familiar with OIDC

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same thing.